# Why does PostgreSQL's SQL require this much unnecessary code for INTERVALs with placeholders?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14

If I try this from PHP:

```
database_query('SELECT * FROM whatever WHERE timestamp < now() - INTERVAL $1', $_GET['number of years back'] . ' year');
```

... I just get a total question mark back from PostgreSQL. It has *no idea* what I'm saying.

Yes, the application makes sure that the variable is really a number, so no need to point that out.

After spending a lot of time trying to hunt down the solution, I eventually landed with this (working) madness:

```
database_query('SELECT * FROM whatever WHERE timestamp < now() - INTERVAL \'1 second\' * $1', convert_fom_time_string_to_Unix_timestamp($_GET['number of years back'] . ' year') - current_Unix_timestamp());
```

This makes the code much uglier and harder to understand and look at. And for seemingly no good reason. Since standardization between databases is a futile task anyway, why not "extend" the SQL standard in this case (if necessary) in order to accept `INTERVAL $1`, as a "syntax shortcut" if you will?

I do not understand why PostgreSQL has to be so "strict for no reason" in these situations.

It should also be mentioned that I tried things such as `::interval` and `::timestamptz`, and searched online and was profoundly confused by the other discussions about this.

Answer (score 2):

> Then I just get a total question mark back from PostgreSQL. It has no idea what I'm saying.
> I do not understand why PostgreSQL has to be so "strict for no reason" in these situations.

It is actually strict **for** a reason: the SQL standard specifies how an interval constant has to be specified and `interval 1 year` does not follow that syntax. Postgres fully supports the SQL standard for specifying interval constants.

The `interval` keyword needs to be followed by a **string** constant with the interval type following the string constant.

An interval of 5 years in fully standard compliant syntax would be: `interval '5' year to month` (yes the precision "year to month" is mandatory in the SQL standard and you only have the choice between `year to month` and `day to second`).

Postgres relaxes the syntax and also allows to mix the two units by specifying e.g. `interval '1 year 3 months 20 days 5 hours 42 minutes'` which is *not* allowed as per the SQL standard.

But it still has to be a string **constant**. Pretty much like specifying an ISO date or timestamp constant: `timestamp '2022-12-17 18:19:20'`

---

In your case where you want to provide a number of years as a parameter, there is no need to convert back and forth between seconds and unix epoch. You can multiply an interval of 1 year with your parameter that represents years:

```
WHERE timestamp < now() - interval '1 year' * $1
```

Alternatively you can use `make_interval()`

```
WHERE timestamp < now() - make_interval(years => $1)
```

Comment: Apart from the format of the string, I think there is a legitimate question buried here about the mechanism of supplying that string.  Why is `INTERVAL $1` not allowed but `$1::interval` is allowed?

Comment: (Which question is not restricted to intervals.  `INTEGER $1` is also not allowed in a context where that might make sense)

Comment: @jjanes: `interval ....` must follow the rules of the SQL standard (which simply doesn't support "dynamic values"), whereas `::interval` is Postgres' proprietary cast syntax